# Расстановка переносов в русских словах

Tags: python, строки, текст

Недавно пробегала тема (автор ее почему-то удалил потом) с просьбой помочь в реализации расстановки переносов в русских словах на Python. Условие данное им было таким:

***а***) две идущие подряд гласные можно разделить, если первой из них предшествует согласная,
а за второй идет хотя бы одна буква (буква й при этом рассматривается с предшествующей
гласной как единое целое);
**б**) две идущие подряд согласные можно разделить, если первой из них предшествует гласная,
а в той части слова, которая идет за второй согласной, имеется хотя бы одна гласная
(буквы ь,ъ при этом рассматриваются как единое целое с предшествующей согласной);
**в**) если правила, указанные в пунктах (а) и (б) применить невозможно, то следует
попытаться разбить слово так, чтобы первая часть содержала более чем одну букву и
оканчивалась на гласную, а вторая содержала хотя бы одну гласную.

Не уверен, что полностью реализовал выполнение всех условий, поэтому если будут предложения по оптимизации, с удовольствием приму.

Если работа скрипта устроит, пользуйтесь на здоровье, если кому нужно. ***Код в ответе.***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encode: utf-8 -*-

def w_wrap(word: str) -> str:
    def is_vow(let: str) -> bool:
        _vowels = ['а', 'о', 'и', 'е', 'ё', 'э', 'ы', 'у', 'ю', 'я', 'А', 'О', 'И', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Э', 'Ы', 'У', 'Ю', 'Я']
        return let in _vowels

    def is_cons(let: str) -> bool:
        _consonants = ['б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'щ',
                       'ш', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Ж', 'З', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч',
                       'Ш', 'Щ']
        return let in _consonants

    def vow_inds(wrd: str):
        return [i for i in range(len(wrd) - 2) if is_vow(wrd[i])]

    vow_indices = vow_inds(word)
    if vow_indices and vow_indices[0] + 2 < len(word):
        for ind in vow_indices:
            sep = '-'
            ind += 1

            if (is_cons(word[ind]) or word[ind] in 'йЙ') and not is_vow(word[ind + 1]):
                ind += 1
            if len(word[:ind]) == 1:  # не даем отделять единичные гласные
                sep = ''
            if len(word) > 3 and word[ind] in 'ьЬЪъ':
                if word[-1] in 'ьЬЪъ':
                    sep = ''
                ind += 1

            return word[:ind] + sep + w_wrap(word[ind:])
    return word


t_word = input('Введите слово: ')

print('Варианты расстановки переносов слова "{}" - [ {} ]'.format(t_word, w_wrap(t_word)))
```

Пример:

```
print(w_wrap('собака'))            # со-ба-ка
print(w_wrap('обезьяна'))          # обезь-яна
print(w_wrap('программирование'))  # прог-рам-ми-ро-ва-ние
```

Comment: Если использовать .lower(), то количество букв в списках сократится в два раза.

Comment: @Эникейщик, cогласен. Так и есть, только как потом вернуть слово к первоначальному виду если оно было написано с заглавной буквы (к примеру)